# applying a constraint on the neural net

Tags: matlab

I want to incorporate an equation in my neural network that relates the outputs of the NN to some of the inputs. The equation is this:  `(K((T-d)-(g-d))/log((T-d)/(g-d))) - (m*Cp*(T-g))`. In this equation, T and K are the outputs of the neural net, and d,g,m, and Cp are the features. I want the network to minimize the data error function(for example MSE) and satisfies this equation, at the same time. Would you please share your ideas with me?

I am not sure if I have to include the equation in the performance function. If yes, how is that possible?